# How to crawl a website that uses cookies while integrating IP proxy?

Tags: c#, cookies, proxy, web-crawler, scraper

I'm creating a crawler which uses several IP Proxies. Whenever I tried to crawl the website without proxy, I'm able to get the html source, but when I tried to enable the ip proxy, it always fail and throws an exceptions (The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.)

Upon looking at the fiddler, it seems the website stores cookies upon visit. But if the proxy is enabled, it fails at get response part.

I don't understand why the cookies was not set using a proxy? Is it the proxy server settings for cookies that cause it? or I can do something about it while still enabling proxy?

I'm using C# by the way, but the question doesn't seems language dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is that you set a cookie from the ip address of the non proxied machine (which worked), then when you sent another request with the same cookie from another ip address which might have gotten you blocked.

Some network level software looks at stuff like this which might have flagged you as a malicious crawler or annonymous tor browser.